# Getting data from mysql in result array and batch updating

Tags: codeigniter

I need a quick solutions to this problem as I'm getting uninitialized offset 2 error codes

```
    $this->db->select('bprice');
    $this->db->from('items');
    $this->db->limit(20);
    $query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

    $data = array();

    foreach($query as $key => $value){

        $data = array(
            'branch_price' => (float)$value['bprice'][$key] + ((float)$value['bprice'][$key] * 0.30)
        );

    }

    return $this->db->update_batch('items',$data);
```

Comment: You need "quick solutions", eh?  SUGGESTION: put "printf" statements in your foreach loop.  Print the value of `$key`, and make sure that both `$value['bprice'][$key]` and `$value['bprice'][$key]` exist and have meaningful values. [print_r()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) can help.

Comment: Your solutions is not very clear to me, please come again

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->db->select('bprice');
$this->db->from('items');
$this->db->limit(20);
$query = $this->db->get()->result_array();

$data = array();

foreach($query as $query){

    $data = array(
        'branch_price' => (float)$query['bprice'] + ((float)$query['bprice'] * 0.30)
    );

}

return $this->db->update_batch('items',$data);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it is insisting that I specify index for batch updates